# displaying image in datagridviewimagecolumn in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a datagridviewimagecolumn which I added using the small arrow when you click the datagridview or should I say not programmatically added.

Can anyone tell me how to display image in datagridviewimagecolumn when the form loads?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Programmatically Add Image

This will add `YourImage.png` to the **first** row (*`Rows(0)`*) in `DataGridView1`

```
    Dim ColImage As New DataGridViewImageColumn
    Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell

    'Set Name
    ColImage.Name = "ColImg"

    'Set Header text
    ColImage.HeaderText = "Your Image!"

    'Add column to datagridview
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(ColImage)

    'Set image value
    Img.Value = Image.FromFile("C:\YourImage.png")

    'Add the image cell to a row
    DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Add(Img)
```

### Adding Image By DataGridView Interface

Click on the small arrow in the upper right hand corner of your datagridview. Click "**Edit Columns**"

[image: Edit columns]

1. A new window pops up, now click on "**Add**" to add a new column.
2. Another window appears, select "**DataGridViewImageColumn**" as the type in the dropdown menu.
3. Set the *name* and *header text*, then click on **Add**

[image: Add column]

All you need to do next is select the image.

[image: Image properties]

*Tip: Set your ImageLayout to "Zoom" and you'll get a clear image.

Comment: Second solution "Adding Image By DataGridView Interface" doesn't work - at least in VS 2015 Community...Only programmatically works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the `DataGridViewImageColumn.Image` property. More information [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn.image.aspx)